# Vertical order traversal Vs Top view of a Tree

Tags: tree

I want to know is there any difference in vertical order traversal of a tree and the top view of the tree?
Or both mean the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a major difference between a vertical traversal and top view of a tree .
If you perform a vertical traversal of tree , there is a guarantee that you will write down all of it's nodes , while the top view it is not guaranteed that all of the nodes will be written down .

Also the way that vertical traversal happens and the process of extracting top view of the tree , might not be the same .

Hence to answer your question , Vertical Order Traversal of tree is different from Top View of the tree .